# Xamp on fedora fails to start

Tags: apache, xampp, fedora, lampp

I installed xampp and its been working fine, until I started getting the following error whenever I tried to start xampp:

> `XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility librar
>   y for your system.`

After commenting the lines of code in `/opt/lampp/lampp` that referenced this error I now get a new error when launching xampp with `/opt/lampp/lampp start`:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.3-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 10 of /opt/lam
pp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: libnsl.so.1: cannot op
en shared object file: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

I have `php-7.2.3` installed in `/opt/lampp/bin` and apache and everything else was working before. How do I get Apache to launch?

Comment: What line of code you comment out? Show your configuration. The error log also said you have problem with '/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf' and `/opt/lam
pp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`. Seem you got problem with `libnsl.so.1`

Answer (score 3):

it seems you're missing the libnsl, install it through this command:

*# sudo dnf install libnsl*

In case this doesn't work you can then download it manually:

```
visit https://pkgs.org/

in the search box (pkgs.org of course) type libnsl.so.1 and choose the appropriate OS. The version shown might be higher e.g libnsl-2.28-9.fc29.x86_64.rpm, but it doesn't matter, the file needed is also included in this very package.

in the terminal, navigate to the directory where the .rpm was downloaded.

then type the following command to install it:
```

*# sudo rpm libnsl-2.XX-X.fc29.x86_64.rpm*

Upon completion everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following two commands helped me:

1. Open your terminal and run the following command **sudo apachectl stop**
2. Try rerunning your apache server from xammp again.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution

First:

1 - `sudo dnf install libnsl`

if i doesn't work for you then follow the steps bellow:

2 - `sudo vim /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`
go to the line 522 and change it to this `include "/opt/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"`

3 - `sudo vim /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`
go to line 6 and comment it `#LoadModule perl_module     modules/mod_perl.so`

ii'm not using perl and i don't need it. loading perl modules was making the problem.
if you wanna use perl then look for another solution